# Regular Expression * |

Tags: regex

let's say I have reg exp of `(a|b)*(ab)+`
I know that `*` means **0 or more** and `+` means **1 or more** and `|` means **either or**?

so, `aab`, `ab`, `abab`, `bbbbbbbbbbbbab` and `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab` would work.

Trying to understand these notation if it was `(a|b)*|(ab)+` a alone would work, correct?
But a alone wouldnt work for `(a|b)*(ab)+`

Comment: Do you want a link to a regex tutorial/reference?

Comment: I think it's unlikely to be fully explained in a tutorial and is a good question.

Comment: yes please. that would be nice

Comment: Why don't you play around for yourself at http://regexpal.com/

Comment: If he would draw out the DFA, I think it would become very clear for him.

Comment: Not everyone is of that level, Austin.  Hence the purpose of the site; to ask questions from those who may know more.

Comment: regexpal.com is really helpful! thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right.

`(a|b)*|(ab)+` can match `a` only, because it will take the first alternative (`(a|b)*`) and then match exactly one `a`. In fact, this regex would even match an empty string.

`(a|b)*(ab)+` on the other hand cannot choose anything, it may match 0 `(a|b)` but then there has to be at least one `ab`.

Note also, that the first regex is equivalent to `(a|b)*` and `[ab]*`, because this already covers the possibility of repeated `(ab)`. (In fact there is a slight difference in terms of the capturing subgroups, but this is probably beyond what is relevant or applicable for you).

Comment: So then, (a|b)*(ab)+ could even be simplified to just (ab)+. wait no because (ab)+ wouldn't accept aaaaaaaaaab. or would it? ill just play with it at the one website. thank you.

Comment: @antz No, the first expression is not simplifiable. It can, however, be *rewritten* using a character class, as `[ab]*(ab)+` if this is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct across the board.

To draw it out more clearly, or at least as best as I can do without an actual image, we can look at the different parts in sections.

```
(a|b)
```

This will match `a` *or* `b`. Now, if you add a `*` (named "kleene star") to this, it will match 0 or more times:

```
(a|b)*
```

As this is in the beginning of your regex, it's stating that you can have any repeating combination of `a` and/or `b` at the beginning of your input.

The second group:

```
(ab)
```

This requires that there must be an `a` followed by a `b`. Adding a `+` makes it occur 1 or more times:

```
(ab)+
```

So, as this is at the end of your regex, it states that you may have one or more repeating `ab` sequences at the end of our string.

Combined into `(a|b)*(ab)+`, you can have any combination of `a` and `b`, as long as your input ends with at least one `ab`.

If you were to add a `|` between the two sets, the first set to match (with the one on the left of the `|` evaluating first) would be the matched set.

With this, `(a|b)*|(ab)+` can match just `a` because `(a|b)` can match just `a` - and this group is on the left of the `|` so it's evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

Let's translate.

1. `(a|b)*(ab)+` means:

   - Zero or more of ("a" or "b")
   - **Followed by** one or more of "ab"

   Therefore, any of `ab`, `bab`, `aab`, `abab`, `aaababbab` would work; but `a`, `b`, `aaa`, `bbb`, `bbba`, `<empty>` would not.
2. `(a|b)*|(ab)+` means:

   - Zero or more of ("a" or "b")
   - **Or** by one or more of "ab"

   Therefore, all of the above would match because they would all match the first alternative `(a|b)*`. Some also just *happen* to match the second alternative `(ab)+` but it actually doesn't matter - the second alternative is completely covered by the first and will never be checked!

Answer (score 1):

```
(a|b)*|(ab)+
```

`(a|b)*` means 0 or more characters that can be a or b. In other words, any combination of 'a' and 'b'. `(ab)+` means 1 or more 'ab'. Place the `|` between them and it means one or the other. So yes, 'a' alone would work.

```
(a|b)*(ab)+
```

The first portion is the same, 0 or more characters that can be 'a' or 'b'. However there is no '|' which means concatenation. So after your sequence of 'a' and 'b', it is followed by 1 or more 'ab'.

I suggest you read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). It explains the three operations in formal regular expressions: kleene star, altercation, and concatenation. As well as how real-world regex engines work.